# Is every loop in a 3-manifold homotopic to some loop on its boundary?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider a solid region of Euclidean 3-space, or more precisely, a compact, connected 3-dimensional submanifold $U \subset E^3$ bounded by a smooth oriented surface $\Sigma = \partial U$.  Very roughly speaking, can one find a representative of each homotopy class of loops in $U$ as a loop on the boundary?  More precisely:

**Question:** For every loop $\gamma$ in the fundamental group $\pi_1(b,U)$ (where $b$ is any point of $U$), does there exist a loop $\tilde{\gamma}$ homotopic to $\gamma$ that is contained entirely in $\Sigma$?

By homotopic here, we of course mean that $\gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}$ are related by a homotopy *in* $U$, not just in $E^3$.  I.e., there exists some continuous map $\Gamma: [0,1] \times S^1 \to U$ such that $\Gamma(0,s) = \gamma(s)$ and $\Gamma(1,s) = \tilde{\gamma}(s)$.

Comment: Just to be clear, in my situation I do not require all the loops $\tilde{\gamma}$ to be based at the same point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**In case we do wish to fix a basepoint on $\Sigma$:**

Consider a torus $\Sigma=T^2$ in $E^3$, and let $U$ be the closure of the bounded region of $E^3-\Sigma$.

One option is that $U$ is a solid torus, in which case the induced map $\pi_1(\Sigma)\to \pi_1(U)$ is surjective.

The other option is that $U$ is a nontrivial knot complement.  For example, the following is a trefoil knot complement:

[image: trefoil knot complement]

But $\pi_1(\Sigma)\to\pi_1(U)$ can't possibly be surjective because $\pi_1(U)$ is nonabelian (in fact it is the three-strand braid group) yet $\pi_1(\Sigma)\cong\mathbb{Z}^2$.

**In case we do not wish to fix a basepoint on $\Sigma$:**

Let $U$ be $B^3$ minus a split unlink.  This is a compact submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with three boundary components: a sphere and two tori. A loop that is the composite of the meridians of the two link components is not homotopic to a loop on the boundary.  This is true even homologically.

The following paper has something to say about compact oriented manifolds where every loop is freely homotopic to a loop in the boundary:

*Brin, Matthew; Johannson, Klaus; Scott, Peter*, [**Totally peripheral 3-manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1985.118.37), Pac. J. Math. 118, 37-51 (1985). [ZBL0525.57010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0525.57010).

If every loop in $U$ is freely homotopic to one in $\Sigma$ (that is, if $U$ is "totally peripheral"), then their result implies that there is some component $F$ of $\Sigma$ such that $\pi_1(F)\to\pi_1(U)$ is surjective.

Applying this to the case of a compact component of a torus complement in $E^3$, this only happens if $U$ is a solid torus (the complement of a trivial knot), since the fundamental group of a nontrivial knot complement is nonabelian.

In general, a compact orientable irreducible 3-manifold $U$ is a *compression body* if there is a boundary component $F\subset \Sigma$ with $\pi_1(F)\to\pi_1(U)$ surjective.  Marden's *Outer Circles* example 3-11 (p. 168) explains how this works.  A quick definition: a compression body is the boundary connect sum of a handle body with some number of surface-cross-intervals.  All of these can be embedded in $E^3$.  This should handle the complete classification of compact $U$ since (1) being in $E^3$ means there are no $S^1\times S^2$ connect summands and (2) $U$ has to be prime for this surjectivity condition to hold due to van Kampen's theorem.

---

I came up with the following before I dug up the above reference.  Consider the trefoil complement again.  Loops that are homotopic to boundary loops are called *peripheral elements*, and they are conjugate to an element in the image of $\pi_1(\Sigma)\to\pi_1(U)$, or equivalently if they are in some peripheral subgroup.  In the following we'll see that $\pi_1(U)$ has non-peripheral elements. (Though $\pi_1(U)$ is certainly generated by them.)

Consider the presentation $G=\pi_1(U)=\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^3\rangle$ (as seen in Hatcher), where $\mu=y^{-1}x$ is a meridian and $\lambda=xy$ is a corresponding longitude (with $\mu^{-5}xy$ being a zero-framed longitude), which together generate a peripheral subgroup.  There is a homomorphism $f:G\to \operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}])$ given by
\begin{align}
x&\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}0&t\\-t^2&0\end{bmatrix}\\
y&\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}0&t\\-t&t\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
called the *Burau representation*, at least after removing the trivial subrepresentation --- this particular presentation comes from https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0103008 via [John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week233.html). (Interesting fact 1: this representation is faithful.  Interesting fact 2: if $a:G\to\mathbb{Z}$ is the abelianization with $a(\mu)=1$, then $\det(f(g))=t^{a(g)}$.)

Since $\mu$ and $\lambda$ generate an abelian subgroup, the subgroup's image under $f$ is simultaneously diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Q}(t)$.  With
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{1-t}&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},$$
then
\begin{align}
f(\mu)&=P\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&t\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}\\
f(\lambda)&=P\begin{bmatrix}-t^3&0\\0&-t^2\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}.
\end{align}
Every peripheral subgroup has an image generated by some conjugate of these generators.  In particular, images of peripheral elements are conjugate to a matrix of the form
$$(-1)^m\begin{bmatrix}t^{3m}&0\\0&t^{m+n}\end{bmatrix}$$
for some $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.  But, $f(x)$ does not diagonalize over $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ since its characteristic polynomial is $a^2+t^3$.  Therefore $x$ is not a peripheral element.  Similarly, neither is $y$.

(I think there might be a geometric way to see this by thinking about the universal cover of $U$ as $\mathbb{H}^2\times \mathbb{R}$ with the deck transformations being isometries.  Peripheral subgroups are lattices inside flat planes (products of hyperbolic lines and $\mathbb{R}$), and conjugation transforms the plane and lattice.  I think that some elements are "too close" to the identity to be on any such lattice, and I would appreciate it if anyone could explain the details of this to me.)

Comment: (In case it helps anyone else, there is a picture of a knot complement about 1/4 of the way down the page here: https://www.ias.edu/ideas/2016/agol-hyperbolic-link-complements, which helped me better understand Kyle's drawing

Comment: I think this requires some small further argument for unbased homotopy. For instance, the map $\Bbb Z/4 \to Q$ embedding the imaginaries into the quaternions is surjective on conjugacy classes. I don't know why the union of peripheral subgroups doesn't cover the whole group at a glance.

Comment: Terrific---many thanks for the quick response.  Just to be clear, in my situation I do not require all the loops $\tilde{\gamma}$ to be based at the same point; only the loops $\gamma$.  So the question Mike Miller raises is relevant.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I modified the picture in a way that is hopefully clearer.

Comment: @MikeMiller I just asserted that there are non-peripheral elements without argument, and I'll admit it took me a while to actually come up with a proof.

Comment: Impressive update. I wish I could upvote again. I would expect that any nontrivial knot has a non-peripheral element of $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus K)$, but I don't know how I would try to prove that.

Comment: @Kyle:  I agree that this is clearer, but the first one was fine as well.  I've just never thought about embeddings of $T^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which don't bound a solid torus.  I was having trouble realizing that the "inside" of the small tube is actually part of the complement of $U$.

Comment: @JacquesMartin I've edited the answer with an explicit element that is non-peripheral.

Comment: @MikeMiller I found a paper that implies there are always non-peripheral elements. I think it could be strengthened to say that $U$ must be a handlebody minus balls if it were totally peripheral, but I'm not sure if boundary connect summands inherit total peripherality. (Deleted argument in edit history.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch Kyle, these answers are very useful.  Unfortunately it seems I don't yet have enough "reputation points" to give you an upvote, but will be sure to do so once I do!

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is great.